# How to migrate EC2 isntance from aws to azure (ubuntu 16.04 instance)

Tags: amazon-web-services, azure, amazon-ec2, amazon-ami

I have AWES EC-2 instances with Ubuntu 16.04 , how to migrate them to Microsoft azure?

I have their image Amazon Machine Images (AMI) on amazon web services, is there a way I could migrate the images to azure ? or the instance configuration? I prefer copy the image I have create in amazon web services (with Ubuntu 16.04 base) to azure.

I have seen this documentation: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/site-recovery/migrate-tutorial-aws-azure but it does not specify Ubuntu support and it copy the instance, can I copy the image? and can it be perform with ubuntu 16.04?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you see, all the support OS version show there. So, unfortunately, it does not support Ubuntu to migrate from AWES to Azure. For Linux, it just supports a part of Red Hat and Centos versions.

For the image, it's possible to export the VM to a VHD file and upload the Azure, but it just shows the Windows VM. You can get the whole steps from [Move a Windows VM from Amazon Web Services (AWS) to an Azure virtual machine](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/windows/aws-to-azure?toc=%2Fazure%2Fvirtual-machines%2Flinux%2Ftoc.json). You can try for Linux, but I'm not sure about it.

If you have any more questions, please let me know. Or if you think it's OK you can accept it :-)

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you strongly consider implementing the base instance configuration as a userdata or init script. This start up script would install all required software and configuration settings on the instance.

This way you can simply run the script on the Azure instance,  and it will work exactly as it would on the AWS instance.

This approach is best practice for managing a baseline configuration of any instance. You can also consider configuration management tools like Ansible to do the same.